# Error with radiobuttons on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Why does the below code show me an error? Please correct this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex='0') 
    {
        Response.Redirect("page1.aspx");
    }
    else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex='1') 
    {
        Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
    }
    else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex='2') 
    {
        Response.Redirect("page3.aspx");
    }
}
```

My design code is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem>item1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>item2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>item3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList></div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Kyle - Cannot implicitly convert int to bool

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SelectedIndex` is an `int`, not a string:

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0) 
{
    Response.Redirect("page1.aspx");
}
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1) 
{
    // and so on
}
```

Comment: You need to change the `=` to `==`.

Answer (score 6):

Because SelectedIndex is an integer, not a character. Get rid of the single quotes. And `=` is an assignment operator, not a comparison.

Change it to

```
if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 0) 
{
    Response.Redirect("page1.aspx");
}
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 1) 
{
    Response.Redirect("page2.aspx");
}
else if (RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex == 2) 
{
    Response.Redirect("page3.aspx");
}
```

Comment: @karthik, see the update. In an if statement you need something that evaluates to a bool.